# I have an up to date Android SDK,I can not see 'design tab' in android studio?(Read all similar answers but nothing worked)

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I downloaded Android Studio and 'IntelliJ' latest update. My SDK is up to date. But I can not see design tab for the activity_main.xml file. I am a newbie in android programming. Can not understand what is missing?
I am posting the snapshot of IDE.
Please try to solve the problem. If you need more details I will provide them as asked.
Thank You! [image: IntelliJ Android Studio Snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE is downloading `Gradle`, just wait till the download completes successfully.
If `Gradle` has downloaded, just do `Clean project` or `Rebuild project`.

Comment: Ok.... Thanks that was a valuable advice. I will check after 'Gradle' downloads and will then accept the answer. Thank You!